# Accessing child attributes from parent Factory Girl factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, factory-bot

I'm implementing Factory Girl as a replacement for fixtures in my Rails app.  I have several tables that I'm trying to represent using associations.  However, to throw a kink into the loop, beyond just defining the associations, I also need to access attributes of the child factories from the parent.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

- Factory :foo_bar is associated to Factory :foo, which is associated to Factory :bar
- From :foo_bar, I'm trying to access attributes of both :foo and :bar

Here are the samples:

```
Factory.define :bar do |e|
  e.name          "Bar"
end

Factory.define :foo do |e|
  e.bar         {|b| b.association(:bar)}
end

Factory.define :foo_bar do |b|
  f = b.association(:foo)
  b.foo_id      foo.id
  b.bar_id      foo.bar_id
end
```

I've gone through a number of tutorials and other questions and haven't seen any examples of how to do this.  Any ideas, or other ways of getting the same result?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

Based on a couple of the questions, here are some clarifications that I should have included originally...

:foo_bar is not a join table, but a model with other attributes of its own.

This is what I'm actually trying to accomplish:

- have :foo_bar create an associated Factory
- then have that associated Factory create it's associated Factory
- (this is the element I'm struggling with) have :foo_bar access an attribute from the bottom level Factory

So, if :foo_bar > :foo > :bar then from :foo_bar, I'm trying to get at :bar's ID.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what :foo_bar is. Is it just a join table or does it have other properties that aren't listed?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the comment.  Yeah, I can see how it's confusing from the simplified version.  :foo_bar has other attributes that just aren't shown.  It's not a join table.

Comment: This is the thread that I have been looking at, fyi: http://groups.google.com/group/factory_girl/browse_thread/thread/2ffdd38eb31b0727?pli=1

Comment: Perhaps you could update :foo_bar after creating the bottom level Factory using the `after_create` callback provided by FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using an after_build hook to handle situations like this:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  f.name "Foo"
  f.association :foo
  f.after_build do |obj|
    obj.foo_bar = obj.foo.bar
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell how it should look without the model code?

but maybe something like this?

```
Factory.define :bar do |f|
    f.name "Bar"
    f.association :foo_bar  
end

Factory.define :foo do |f|
    f.name "Foo"
    f.association :foo_bar  
end

Factory.define :foo_bar do |f|
    f.association :foo
    f.association :bar      
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think my example didn't clearly illustrate the full question.  I'll revise it to be more clear, but what I'm actually trying to do is have :foo_bar create an associated Factory, and then have that associated Factory create it's associated Factory, but (and this is the element I'm struggling with) also have :foo_bar access an attribute from the bottom level Factory.  So, :foo_bar > :foo > :bar and from :foo_bar, I'm trying to get at :bar's ID.  Does that make more sense?